# Impossible to configure SharePoint 2019

Tags: database, windows, sharepoint, windows-server, keyset

I am in Master 2 in Cybersecurity and one of our subjects is to replay a CVE vulnerability. I chose Sharepoint CVE-2023-29357. I've been trying to install a Sharepoint server for several days but it's impossible.
The flaw being patched in the latest updates, I am forced to use an old version of SharePoint for example available with Vagrant images like:

- https://app.vagrantup.com/SubPointSolutions/boxes/win-2016-datacenter-sp2016latest-sql16-vs17
- https://app.vagrantup.com/SubPointSolutions/boxes/win-2012r2-datacenter-sp2013sp1-sql16-vs17
- https://app.vagrantup.com/SubPointSolutions/boxes/win-2016-datacenter-sp2019latest-sql16-vs17

Once the VM is turned on, I create an Active Directory because I am required to have a domain to continue the SharePoint configuration (the configuration using the command does not work either "Server execution failed" due to an SQL problem in one of the lines). I also install a SQL instance of Microsoft SQL 2016.

I will need help with the issue of configuration failing at some point during SharePoint setup. The error is:
[image: Error Configuration SharePoint]

"Keyset does not exist"
I followed all the tutorials I could find on this problem but nothing helped...

I am running Kali Linux with a Windows Server 2016 VM and a version of SharePoint 2019 with this Vagrant box: - https://app.vagrantup.com/SubPointSolutions/boxes/win-2016-datacenter-sp2019latest-sql16-vs17

With the SharePoint Management Shell I got the same error:
[image: SMS Problem]

The log:

> An exception of type System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Keyset does not exist (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090016)
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80090016): Keyset does not exist (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090016)
> at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostWritableAdminManager.CommitChanges()
> at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.CommitChanges()
> at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.CommitChanges()
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisServerManager.CommitChanges(ApplyChanges applyChanges)
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisProvisioningAssistant.ProvisionApplicationPoolInternal(String name, ProcessModelIdentityType identityType, SecurityIdentifier sid, String password, SPIisApplicationPoolSettings settings)
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisManager.ProvisionApplicationPool(String name, SecurityIdentifier sid, SecureString password, SPIisApplicationPoolSettings settings)
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool.ProvisionLocal(SPIisWebServiceApplicationPoolProvisioningOptions options)
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceApplication.ProvisionApplicationInstance()
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceApplication.ProvisionLocal(SPServiceInstance serviceInstance)
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPSecurityTokenServiceApplication.ProvisionLocal(SPServiceInstance serviceInstance)
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceInstance.Provision()
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Join(Boolean skipRegisterAsDistributedCacheHost, Nullable`1 serverRole)
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb()
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.Run()
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Thanks in advance !!